# Find $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$ if $\theta = \frac{n\pi}{2}$ and $\theta = \frac{2m\pi}{5} + \frac{\pi}{10}$, where $n,m$ are integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, least-common-multiple

> $\theta = \dfrac{n\pi}{2}$ and $\theta = \dfrac{2m\pi}{5} + \dfrac{\pi}{10}$ where $ n ,m \in \mathbb Z$. Find  $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$.

It can be solved by hit and try, of course but is there any faster way? Maybe concept of least common multiple can crack it? I tried that but I realised I was only taught to find LCM for natural numbers and not complicated equations.
I found a problem which asked me to solve a trigonometric equation and I did until I got stuck here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Better to use words in your title instead of using Latex only.

Comment: @StubbornAtom can you please suggest a better title? Or give an example.

Comment: As you can see I edited your title with some formatting adjustments. You can see this in the [edit history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3182436/revisions). Related threads on Meta: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-rm-latex-in-question-titles, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: @StubbornAtom titles are supposed to be short   so I usually don't add details like range of $\theta$ and unnecessary language. But I will take care of your suggestion next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\dfrac{n\pi}2=\dfrac{(4m+1)\pi}{10}$

$\iff5n=4m+1\iff5(n-1)=4(m+1)$

$\dfrac{4(m-1)}5=n-1$ which is an integer

$\implies5$ divides $4(m-1)$

$\implies 5$ divides $m-1$ as $(4,5)=1$

WLOG $m-1=5r$ where $r$ is an integer

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the last step?

Comment: Do you mean why $m-1=5r?$

Comment: 4(m-1) should be a multiple of five , so. 4(m-1) = 5r where r is a integer..... I got that.  But what happened next ?

Comment: But $4,5$ don't have a common factor$>1$

Comment: thank you got that .

Comment: @labbhattacharjee:  on the first line you have $\pi$ on the left but not the right !?

Comment: @Tanner, The typo has been rectified. Thanks