# If $\frac{5m-1}{4} =n$ m,n $\in$ Z integer then find general solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $\dfrac{5m-1}{4} =n$ m,n $\in$ Z (integer) then find general solution. Answer is m = 4k -3, n= 5k-4. $k\in$ Z(integer)
According to me answer should be 1+4n=5k , 5m-1=4k.
Can you please explain where did I go wrong ?
I am a high school students who is self studying for college entrance exam. Original problem was a trigonometric equation which I solved but didn't get the correct answer.
Thanks you.

Comment: You wrote $1+4n=5k$ but should be $1+4n=5m$; also you wrote $5m-1=4k$ but should be $5m-1=4n$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner it is suppose to be in general form , m should be independent of n and vice versa. So I needed another variable integer.

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182436/find-theta-in-0-2-pi-if-theta-fracn-pi2-and-theta-frac2m-pi/3182446#3182446

Comment: I would not say $m$ is independent of $n$ if $\dfrac{5m-1}{4} =n$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee they are two completely different questions. Thanks for taking time to check them.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I have to solve it in such a way so that m and n are expressed independent of each other. So I have make both of them  express on a different variable say 'k'. Yeah you are right. They are not independent I should have said express from the very beginning. I am sorry of that.

Comment: @swarnim, If one understands the method in the linked post, I believe one can solve this, too.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I tried but I didn't get the correct answer. My answer and correct answer is in the details of the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\dfrac{5m-1}{4} =n$ with  $m,n \in \mathbb Z $ , then  $m$ and $n$ are not independent of each other;

they satisfy $1+4n=5m$ (you wrote $5k$) or  $5m-1=4n$ (you wrote $4k$).

From $1+4n=5m$ we see $5$ divides $4n+1$  so $5$ divides $4n+1+15=4n+16=4(n+4)$

so $5$ divides $n+4$ (since $5$ is prime and does not divide $4$) so $5k=n+4$ so $n=5k-4$ with $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Therefore $m=\dfrac{1+4n}5=\dfrac{1+4(5k-4)}5=\dfrac{20k-15}5 =4k-3.$

Comment: Alternatively, I could have said $5m-1=4n \implies 4n\equiv-1\pmod5\implies n\equiv1\pmod5 \implies n=5k-4 $ so $m=\dfrac{1+4n}5 = \dfrac{1+20k-16}5 = \dfrac{20k-15}5=4k-3$ with $k\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Can you please explain what "$ 5 m  \equiv 1 (mod 4) "$ means.  It's the first time I am seeing this kind of expression. I thought $\equiv and =$ mean basically the same thing.

Comment: $5m\equiv1\pmod4$ means $4$ divides $5m-1$

Comment: $k = K+1$ looks arbitrary. Can you please explain that.

Comment: $4K+1$ is the same as $4k-3$ -- I merely wanted to switch to the form you said was the answer -- but anyway I revamped my answer so I no longer use [modulo notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) or $K$